# Porting a blog from WordPress to BlogEngine.NET

Tags: xml, blogengine.net

I'm porting a blog from WordPress to BlogEngine.NET. I've written a small WinForm app in C# which reads in all the web pages (i.e., posts) from the WordPress site and outputs an XML file for each post (by default, BlogEngine.NET uses XML to store its posts, and that will work fine for my purposes). Then, I FTP'd them up to the BlogEngine.NET site and put them under App_Data/posts.

At that point, I navigated to the "Posts" page of the blog where I expected to see a list of all the posts. Unfortunately, only the single sample post included with BlogEngine.NET shows up. I actually stole the code that BlogEngine.NET uses to create the XML files in order to port the posts from WordPress and create the XML files, so I'm pretty sure my files are in the correct format.

Why aren't my posts showing up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Did you restart the app_pool of your website?

Any time you upload directly to the site through ftp or file manager you need to restart the app_pool so that it can refresh the in system memory with your new posts/pages.

1. Can you post here an exact copy of one of the xml file post that was imported?

To me since you did not receive an error more likely seems to be an app_pool restart issue.

You can restart the app_pool by re uploading your web.config file or go to

extensions then enable and disable if you want to do it from with in the BE admin panel.

You can also try to work with it on your local computer.  Download the entire site and try to run from local computer.

If it works on local but not server then its a server issue.